# My window doesn't paint properly when it's not running in the debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I have a Win32 program (desktop app) that works fine when debugging (started by <kbd>F5</kbd>), but it doesn't paint the window, nor its title when run without debugging (<kbd>Ctrl + F5</kbd>). How is that possible ? I'm using VS 2010.

Edit: in Release build the code works fine with without debugging, but it doesn't in the debugger, which is exactly the opposite of what happens in Debug build.

New Edit:

After many hours working on this, I found out that the problem somehow is related to the initialization of a static std::auto_ptr object with its reset() member function.

Remember what I said above, that the window title doesn't show on the app window, and this title is set up with SetWindowText(hwnd, L"Any Title") at the end of the WM_CREATE message processing. I then started moving backwards this function call, within WM_CREATE, to see exactly where it failed to exhibit the window's title. And that occurs after the first initialization of a static std::auto_ptr object like the pseudo-code below :

```
class A{};

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, UINT wParam, LONG lParam)
{
    static std::auto_ptr<A> a;
    switch ( message )
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            ...
            a.reset(new A);
            SetWindowText(hwnd, L"Any Title");
            ...
        }
        break;

        case WM_PAINT:

        ...

        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:

        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

        default:

        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That means, if I call SetWindowText() before the initialization of the variable `a`, the window title is shown correctly, although it doesn't show any text on its client area, when the window gets painted. I know the window is being painted, for I inserted a `MessageBeep(-1)` in `WM_PAINT`, and I can hear the sound.

It's also interesting to mention that everything that is printed in WM_PAINT comes from `class A` objects allocated on the heap, whose addresses are encapsulated in `std::auto_ptr` objects.

Of course, all this is happening when executing the code with <kbd>Ctrl + F5</kbd>. When the program is launched with <kbd>F5</kbd> everything works fine.

New Edit :

I changed the `std::auto_ptr` variables to `unique_ptr` to no avail. The problem continues.

Comment: How are you handling the event?

Comment: What do you mean ? Which event ?

Comment: I mean the press of F5 versus Ctrl-F5. There should be, according to your explanation, a handler for F5 that's doing something to disallow F5, and by handler I mean `WM_KEYDOWN` or a similar message. It would also help to know how exactly it's "working with F5".

Comment: F5 in VS2010 executes the selected project under the debugger. The Ctrl + F5 executes the project directly under VS, which means the code doesn't stop on any break point, for example.

Comment: Oh, I was misled with the whole "Win32 program" and painting thing. I thought you were talking about refreshing your window or something.

Comment: @chris - you are forgiven, the question is horribly unanswerable.  Never stop asking why?  :)

Comment: @HansPassant Why unanswerable ? Look at this site http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/09/22/f5-vs-ctrlf5.aspx. I'm not doing anything mentioned here. Is this a bug ?

Comment: I don't think I need to answer this

Comment: You really need to update the question to say that `F5` is being pressed in Visual Studio to launch your app, not being pressed while your application's window has focus.

Comment: What are the extra braces for in the `WM_CREATE` handler?  Might you be declaring a local variable in that block that hides the outer `a`?  Also, the order of messages at startup can be confusing.  Perhaps you should allocate `A` on `WM_NCCREATE`.

Comment: I have several local variables declared inside those braces in my real code. Remember this is just a very simple approximation to the real code. There's no chance of hiding the static variables, as all of them start with 's_' (think in terms of `s_a` instead of `a`, and you'll understand what I'm saying. All these `'a'` (or `s_a`) objects (in my real code there are several of them) are created and initialized in WM_CREATE and printed in WM_PAINT. That's all the program is doing, although this initialization isn't simple. Actually the code in WM_CREATE is pretty extensive.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a timing issue (might be anything but unexplainable behavior is more often than not some kind of race condition). Add debug traces on relevant events/overrides to see what is going on.

Comment: I have just one thread of execution and I'm not using any timers in this program. One thing I noticed. After inserting a MessageBeep() in the paint procedure, I can hear the sound, which means the window is being painted, but the characters don't show up.

Comment: Another strange thing is this : I establish a new title for the Window with SetWindowTitle(hwnd, L"Any Title") in WM_CREATE, but the title doesn't show up. How can this happen ?

Comment: I meant to say SetWindowText(hwnd, L"Any Title"), instead of SetWindowTitle(hwnd, L"Any Title")